# Amazon Product Advertising API NewReleases / keword-search

Tags: php, search, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

i try to find a way to combine the 'NewReleases' ResponseGroup and a keyword search.

I am using the [PHP Soap Library](https://github.com/Exeu/Amazon-ECS-PHP-Library).

I know it is no longer maintained because here is the [new version](https://github.com/Exeu/apai-io) , but i think this doesn´t matter because how you can combine different operations is defined by Amazon.

So what i need in detail is:

i want for example make an call for NewReleases in Action DVD´s (DE) like so:

```
$response = $amazonEcs->responseGroup('NewReleases')->browseNodeLookup(289093);
```

But then i want to perform a keyword-search operation on this for example -> 'x-men'.

i couldn´t find a way to resolve this because you can only perform the NewReleases responsegroup on browsenoelookup mentioned [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_NewReleases.html)

and also the sort parameter 'releasedate' doesn´t help because this is only on few categories possible mentioned [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/DESortValuesArticle.html).

so in simple words i want to do a request like this.

```
$response = $amazonEcs->category('All')->responseGroup('Large,NewReleases')->search('x-men');
```

But this is not working because of the BrowseNodeLookup restriction.

The only way i can imagine now is that i do a request on a BrowseNodeId and perform the search by myself, but this would be a lot to an also you are limited to ( 20 requests / 2 minutes ) of the same kind. And this limit i would reach in no time because the browsenodelookup requests only gives back the Title and ASIN-Number and then you would have to do a Itemlookup for each product.

So if anybody would have a simpler way for me i would be happy.

Thanks

Comment: EDIT: The PHP - Soap Library is outdated: This is the new one https://github.com/Exeu/apai-io

Answer (score 1):

I can say now, that this is not possible.

It is just that you can not browse for NewReleases in any root-category. You always have to go one level deeper.

I did it the way i mentioned with some sleep(1) functions, to avoid the request-limit as long as possible.

Comment: what i didn know at the time of writing is, that you don have to make a lookup for each asin.. you can send up to 10 asins in each request .. this will decrease the number of requests a bit